# Eclipse Indigo crashes after installing GWT

Tags: eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I was trying to set up GWT(Google Web Toolkit) on my system using it as a plugin for eclipse Indigo. I am currently on a Ubuntu workstation. Upon restart after the installation, eclipse simply crashes without any error info. I did look around here on stack overflow , as well as on google about what could be done, but the things which seemed to work for others do not seem to work for me.( deleting certain .jar files, deleting the metadata folder in the workspace).

Any help would be great.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There is a bug in Indigo , exposed by the plugin. All that needs to be done is to check for updates first and then install the plugin. The bug has been fixed in one of the point updates.